# How to deal with a function that at every natural input has an output in different base?

Tags: functions, recursion

I have a very messly defined function f(n) over naturals s.t. f(2) = 0.01 and it has a recursive relation for n>2:

f(n) = f(n-1) + (f(n-1)+n-1)/10^(2^n)

But everything inside this relation is in base n (so 10=n for example) and the value of f(n-1) is taken in such a way that it looks identical in base n to its n-1 version (for example, f(2) = 0.01 in binary (1/4 in base-10) and within the expression of f(3), f(2) transforms into 0.01 in base-3 (1/9 in base-10)).

So the question is, can this recursive relation be written without using base conversion and in a more algebraic way?

First few values of this function:

0

0.01 in binary (1/4 in dec)

0.010201 in ternary (100/729 in dec)

0.01020103010201 in base-4 (18952481/268435456 in dec)

etc.

Comment: What are the next values? $0.010201030102010401020103010201$ in base $5$? $0.01020103010201040102010301020105010201030102010401020103010201$ in base $6$?

Comment: Yes! It is increasing palindromes

Comment: Asking because, if yes, then I don't see how your (very informal!) formula with $10^{3n-4}$ produces this sequence. $n+1$ seems to be shifted by an exponential number of places to the right: $2,4,8$ etc - and $f(n-1)$ by *double* that much. In other words, it is not by $3n-4$ places.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I changed it